# I want to write that a person over 18 is not allowed in this section to throw this exception

Tags: java

My question how to change (age >=18) if the user try to change the age of a person over 18 and throw this EXCEPTION "ADULTS SHOULD BE TRANSFERRED" because what i have so far it does allow me to change no execption is throwed

```
     import java.beans.PropertyChangeEvent;
     import java.beans.PropertyVetoException;
     import java.beans.VetoableChangeListener;

    public class Registrar implements VetoableChangeListener {
         int age;
    @Override
    public void vetoableChange(PropertyChangeEvent event)
        throws PropertyVetoException {
    if (event.getPropertyName().equals("age")) {
        String proposedAge = (String)event.getNewValue();
              Integer.parseInt(proposedAge);
          if (age >=18 ) {
               throw new PropertyVetoException("Adult  should be  transferred.", event);
        }
    }
}
```

}

Comment: Where do you change the value of `age`?

Comment: This is absolutely **NOT** the correct way to use `Exceptions`; all sorts of cute baby animals and mythical creatures die horrible painful deaths when you use `Exception` to control program flow!!

Comment: so why I don`t get any errors?

Comment: Why do you think you should get an error? We have no idea what `age` is set to in your running code. This question makes no sense.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You forget to set age:

```
     import java.beans.PropertyChangeEvent;
     import java.beans.PropertyVetoException;
     import java.beans.VetoableChangeListener;

    public class Registrar implements VetoableChangeListener {
         int age;
    @Override
    public void vetoableChange(PropertyChangeEvent event)
        throws PropertyVetoException {
    if (event.getPropertyName().equals("age")) {
        String proposedAge = (String)event.getNewValue();
            age = Integer.parseInt(proposedAge);
          if (age >=18 ) {
               throw new PropertyVetoException("Adult  should be  transferred.", event);
        }
    }
}
```

}

Answer (score 0):

first you need to set the age:

```
age = Integer.parseInt(proposedAge);
```

and then I recommend you use logs or console

```
System.out.println("Adult  should be  transferred");
```

.

```
import java.beans.PropertyChangeEvent;
import java.beans.PropertyVetoException;
import java.beans.VetoableChangeListener;

public class Registrar implements VetoableChangeListener {
   int age;
   @Override
   public void vetoableChange(PropertyChangeEvent event)
       throws PropertyVetoException {
       if (event.getPropertyName().equals("age")) {
           String proposedAge = (String)event.getNewValue();
           age = Integer.parseInt(proposedAge);
           if (age >=18 ) {
               System.out.println("Adult  should be  transferred");
           }
       }
    }
}
```